# ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product$class when using elasticsearch-hadoop for spark

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, hadoop, amazon-emr

I am running a spark-submit job on AWS EMR
to read from an elasticsearch node.

when the job executes this command

python:

```py
es_config = {
    "es.nodes": url_to_my_node,
    "es.port": "9200",
    "es.resource": "my_elasticsearch_index/_doc",
    "es.query": "?q=id:park_rocky-mountain",
    "es.read.metadata": "true",
    "es.nodes.wan.only": "true",
}

df = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") \
    .options(**es_config) \
    .load()
```

or in scala

```scala
val esReadOptions = Map(
    "es.nodes" -> "url_to_my_node",
    "es.port" -> "9200"
)

val df = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
    .options(esReadOptions)
    .load("url_to_my_node")
```

I get the following error:

```
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.<init>(DefaultSource.scala:221)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:350)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:228)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:210)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:171)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product$class
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
```

apparently this is due to either the JAR not being found or not having the right version.

I have checked the presence of the JAR in the spark context:

```
println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"))
> ...
> :/usr/lib/spark/jars/elasticsearch-hadoop-7.17.6.jar
> ...
```

as for version conflicts,
the EMR instance offers the following environment:

EMR version 3.3.2-amzn-0
Using Scala version 2.12.15
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM,
Java 1.8.0_382

and I am using this JAR:
/usr/lib/spark/jars/elasticsearch-hadoop-7.17.6.jar
which should be compatible with scala2.12 and spark 3.x

I have tried multiple different JARs:

- elasticsearch-hadoop-8.9.0.jar
- elasticsearch-hadoop-7.17.6.jar
- opensearch-hadoop-1.0.1.jar

I have tried connecting to different instances of Elasticsearch:

- Elasticsearch sandbox on (latest as of time or writing) version 8.9.0,
- Opensearch instance (backward compatible with Elasticsearch 7.12)
  I have previously positively tested connection: I am able to access those 2 instances via a REST API call using curl or python.requests from the environment.

I have tried connecting

- with python code that invokes pyspark
- using scala directly from the spark-shell.
  I get the same JAVA error as specified above.

I have tried connecting

- from an AWS EMR instance
- from a local spark implementation running on linux mint 20.3 with kernel 5.15.0-78-generic

the class scala/Product has been part of Scala standard library since version 2.3, and here I am using Scala version 2.12. So the error message must be hiding another issue.

Comment: spark  & scala version ?

Comment: Scala version 2.12.15,    Java 1.8.0_382     . the full specs are above , search for 'environment'. thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Finally the solution was to

- include an additional JAR
- find the right configuration to connect to AWS OpenSearch

we used the following:

AWS Opensearch
"version number" : "7.10.2",
"lucene_version" : "8.10.1"

AWS EMR with
spark version 3.3.2-amzn-0
Scala version 2.12.15
Java 1.8.0_382

added the following JARs:

opensearch-hadoop-1.0.1.jar
aws-java-sdk-1.12.531.jar

and used the following configuration:

```
op_config = {
    "opensearch.resource": index,
    "opensearch.nodes": elastic_host,
    "opensearch.port": elastic_port,
    "opensearch.net.ssl": "true",
    "opensearch.net.ssl.cert.allow.self.signed": "true",
    "opensearch.nodes.wan.only": "true",
    "opensearch.aws.sigv4.enabled": "true",
    "opensearch.aws.sigv4.region": aws_region,
    "opensearch.http.timeout": "3m",
}

df = spark.read.format("opensearch").options(**op_config).load()
```

unfortunately, the information on the github page
https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-hadoop
only provides examples in Java and Scala, but porting it to pyspark is feasible, and it is the only valid documentation found out there as of time or writing.